# Horizontal Rule in Silverlight/XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm looking for a way to draw a horizontal rule across my Silverlight App. I'd like to be able to insert it in the XAML rather than the C#. Can't seem to find much via Google or MSDN.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `<Line>` tag.  More info [here, on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).  Also, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SilverlightLine12082008235353PM/SilverlightLine.aspx) is another article you can look at.

Comment: thanks! I kinda feel like an idiot for missing something so simple.

Comment: don't mention it. it happens to us all.

Comment: The first link in this answer is now dead.

Comment: ...and so is the second

Answer (score 18):

Just use something like this:

HRULE:

```
<Border Margin="48,67,30,0" 
        Name="border1" 
        Height="2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="2" />
```

VRULE:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="2" 
        Margin="92,124,0,62" 
        Name="border2" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Width="2" />
```

Comment: forgive me I have no WPF experience, but I just cooked them two up now and tested them both out. They both work. The traditional label
doesn't work so well in WPF for this type of stuff as well as it does in WinForms.

Comment: Yes, in many cases Border is a better choice than Line for this, because you dont have to specify coordinates like you do with Line. The Border will stretch from left to right without you having to figure out the width of the container

Answer (score 17):

Similar to using a border you can also use a rectangle - I believe this is the 'recommended' way to do a horizontal or vertical line rather than using a line element.

```
<Rectangle Height="1" Fill="Black" />
```

Or, if for example you need it below some kind of block element you can always add a border just on the bottom of the element...